# Problems with Javascript. Not able to Update Status

Tags: javascript, facebook, forms

I am using the Javascript to update the user's status when he enters some text in the Text area.
Here's the Javascript for it-

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>

       function updateStatus(){
            var status  =   document.getElementById('status').value;
                FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: status }, function(response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                         alert('Error occured');
                    } else {
                         alert('Status updated Successfully');
                    }
               });

</script>
```

And here's the Form script I am using

```
  <form action="" method="" onsubmit="updateStatus(); return false;">
  <label for="status">Update Status</label>
  <input type="text" id="status" name="status" size="60" VALUE="Whats on Your mind"/>
  <div align="right" style="height:30px; padding:10px 10px;">
  <label id="shareButton">
  <input type="submit" value="Share">
 </label>
 </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

The problem is when I click on Submit the page just gets refreshed.
Any help would be appreciated.
I have uploaded the Entire code for the App at [http://pastebin.com/UqzaBjpb](http://pastebin.com/PSGUyhMb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the status update on the form's onsubmit instead of the button's onclick. Like so:

```
<form action="" method="" onsubmit="updateStatus(); return false;">
  <label for="status">Update Status</label>
  <input type="text" id="status" name="status" size="60" VALUE="Whats on Your mind"/>
  <div align="right" style="height:30px; padding:10px 10px;">
    <label id="shareButton">
      <input type="submit" value="Share">
    </label>
 </div>
</form>
```

Note: It looked like you had an extra div close tag in there so I removed that too.

It also looks like you have not included the js library that would give you FB. Is that included somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried doing those changes but I still get the same page refreshing. Please look at the entire code at http://pastebin.com/UqzaBjpb

Comment: I made the above changes but I m still getting the refreshing of the page. Check the code here http://pastebin.com/PSGUyhMb

Comment: You might want to put the Facebook stuff at the top of the page – at least as a test – just to be sure it's loaded before submitting the form. If it still doesn't work, you have an error in your JS code somewhere that is preventing the onsubmit code from catching your form submission. Use the script debugger in Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools to see if there's an error somewhere.

Comment: I tried doing that too ! But I am not getting exactly where this error is taking place. Could please try the debug the script! http://apps.facebook.com/speakyourstatus/

Comment: Jed could you please try debugging this script yourself ? That would really be helpful !

Comment: For starters, your updateStatus function needs a closing bracket on line 28, above the closing `</script>` tag.

Comment: Is there something wrong with my function updatestatus cause I m getting alert('Error occured'); all the time

Comment: That one I'm not sure about as it's coming from the FB api. If you can't figure that out you might want to ask a new question here on SO.